# How to add a right border to only one colum when using css bootstrap?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, html-table

I am trying to use [css bootstrap framework](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables) in my project

I am using table with the following classes `table table-bordered table-striped`

I want to remove the borders from all the column except the first column.

Here is my table in a fiddler https://jsfiddle.net/8yf0v3xt/16/

Basically in this screenshot, I only want to remove the vertical borders in the red rectangle border.

[image]

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
<thead>
  <tr><th></th><th></th>...</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr><th score="row"><th></td><td></td>...</tr>
...
</tbody>
</table>
```

**EDITED**

Or, if I remove the table-bordered class, how can I only add a column on the very first column? something like this screenshot
[image]

How can I do that?

Comment: @Jay very close! I want to keep the horizontal rows. I only want to remove the vertical rows

Comment: @Jay thank you. That is exactly what I am looking for. Can you please answer the question and explain how did you do it? I will accept your answer. Very much appreciated

Comment: @Jay thank you. would it be possible to eliminae the used of table-bordered class and instead only add a border to the very first column? I also updated my question for clarity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to look into the `:first-child` pseudo selector. [Link here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstchild.asp)

> The :first-child selector is used to select the specified selector, only if it is the first child of its parent.

You can select all of the `td` elements and remove the border from them all with:

```
table tr td { border: none; }
```

And then to add unique styling to just the first element:

```
table tr td:first-child { border: default; } /* Or whatever styling you may wish..
```

The same can be done with `:last-child` which will of course select the last element in oppose to the first.

And if you need to be even more specific again.. You can use `:nth-child(x)` where x is the number of the element that you wanted.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8yf0v3xt/18/

**UPDATE**

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8yf0v3xt/22/

I've removed the `.table-bordered` class and added the following CSS:

```
table { border: 1px solid #ddd; }
table.table tr, table.table tr th, table.table tr td { border: none; }
table.table tr th:first-child, table.table tr td:first-child { border: 1px solid #ddd; }
```

I have used the pseudo selectors like explained above to add styling to just the first column.

Comment: Thank you. the second fiddle is not correct. I need to eliminate the outside border, keep the horizontal border

Comment: Thank you. I think I am over complicating the problem. I removed the borderd class and then on the very first column I added this code `style="border-right: 1px solid #ddd;"` and that did it as well. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: @MikeA No problem. Happy Coding =)