# Border around a specific column in a table in HTML

Tags: html

How do I put a border around a column in a table in HTML?
Do we use colspan for such functions?

Comment: Depending on the control you have over the HTML, you might find the [`<colgroup>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/colgroup) element useful for styling table columns.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS: borders between table columns only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3313456/css-borders-between-table-columns-only)

Comment: See first answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34538684/how-to-add-a-right-border-to-only-one-colum-when-using-css-bootstrap . With minor modification: just select the right child and, if required, use `border-right: .1rem solid #999;` and so on to specify exactly which borders you want to draw.

Answer (score 7):

Here's an example of a column border without styling the same column of each row.
See [`<colgroup>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/colgroup) for more reference.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.outlined {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <colgroup>
    <col>
    <col class="outlined">
    <col span="3">
  </colgroup>
  <tr>
    <td>First</td>
    <td>Second</td>
    <td>Third</td>
    <td>Fourth</td>
    <td>Fifth</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>First</td>
    <td>Yellow</td>
    <td>Third</td>
    <td>Fourth</td>
    <td>Fifth</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>First</td>
    <td>Yellow</td>
    <td>Third</td>
    <td>Fourth</td>
    <td>Fifth</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML code**

```
 <table>
  <tr>
    <th>Expenses</th>
    <th>Cost</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>iPhone 8</td>
   <td>$1200</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>MacBook Pro</td>
    <td>$2800</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">Sum: $4000</td>
   </tr>
 </table>
```

**CSS code**

```
th, td {
border: 2px solid black;
}
```

You can also play around with table{border}

Answer (score -1):

Use;

```
td { border: 1px solid #000000; }
```

colspan is to merge cells. For example; below line merges 2 cells

```
<tr><td colspan="2">Merged Column</td></tr>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_td_colspan

Comment: This is going to add a border on all **cells**, which is not the same as a **column**.

Comment: Yes, it'll. If required for specific column, then we can add a "class" to that column & assign border style to that column alone

Answer (score -2):

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <table style="width:100%">
       <tr>
          <th>Firstname</th>
          <th>Lastname</th> 
          <th>Age</th>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td>Raju</td>
          <td>Kumar</td>
          <td>22</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td>Mohit</td>
          <td>Sharma</td>
          <td>20</td>
       </tr>
   </table>
</body>
</html>
```